# GUI Issue - No image available for insertion

Tags: c#, user-interface, visual-studio-2013

So I got through the first of two assignments all by myself. Now I need to add an image to my GUI form. My textbook instructs me to do the following:

> To associate an image with the PictureBox control, the Image property
>   is selected. This enables you to browse to the location where the
>   image is stored. You can create a separate folder for your images or
>   as was done with this application place the image in the bin\debug
>   directory. Once you select the Image property and click the three
>   dots- ellipsis- the Select Resource dialog box is revealed. Import the
>   image using the Local resource option.

I've imported my .jpg into bin/debug, opened the Image property, but only see that "(none)" image is selected, no ellipsis are visible.

Any fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small arrow on the top right of the PictureBox control.
If you click it a contextual menu appears

Check out this link : [Step 5: Add Controls to Your Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492173.aspx)